# If I own 50% of the house, and my partner rents the home how is the rental income taxed?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, rental-property

I own 50% of a home, which I would like to use to write off the taxes, as I will be paying the bills.  The other person invested 50% up front and they would like to rent out a room in the house.  If they do the rental contract, do I have any tax responsibilities on that income?  Since I would be the primary person paying the loan, can I keep the tax credit without having the responsibility of said income?

Comment: Do you live in the house? Do you and the partner have equal situations, only he's renting out one of the rooms? Can you try to clarify the question?

Comment: I will not be living in the house.  They are living in the house, and they would be renting the room (managing the agreement, looking for people to rent, etc.).  Since the mortgage would be my responsibility, can I take the write off for the mortgage while not including any rental payments on my taxes?

Comment: It sounds like the partner is living there, but its your half being rented out as a rental property.

Comment: No they are doing the renting as well.  I'm just a 'silent partner' with the mortgage, gaining equity in the house, but not using it.

Comment: If you're not living there - how can you deduct anything?

Comment: I can't deduct the mortgage or the real estate taxes?

Comment: @user13582 if its your primary/vacation house or if its a rental property.

Comment: And what are you getting out of paying the interest on a loan for a house that you don't live in and don't get any income from? I suspect someone is scamming you. Be careful, if they're repaying you the money you spend - it is *taxable income* for you.

Comment: Why would you agree to buy a house and pay a mortgage to get appreciation, but no income? In most cases, the rent far exceeds the appreciation.

Comment: @littleadv Its a relative that I'm helping out.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I am not worried about paying out more than I get back, I'm just looking to see if I can get anything.  I'm helping a relative out.

Comment: @user13582 these things can become messy very quickly. You may be required to file a partnership return, just saying.

Comment: "Helping a relative" is a tough one. The IRS can say that you must declare the income whether it's received or not, and then treat the money to the relative as a gift. You can't just buy and pay for a piece of a house and not have the rest of it make sense.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Thank you, I suspect that was the case, but I wanted to know if there was some way to make it work.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Is the income from the renter coming you you? If you aren't being paid anything, you don't have to pay tax on anything. Similarly if you aren't paying any of the running expenses, you can't deduct them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't make much sense. You should probably talk to a licensed tax adviser (EA or CPA licensed in your state), with more detailed explanation of the specifics of your situation.

In general, you cannot write off something you own, unless you use it to produce income. So just owning a home doesn't entitle you to any write offs. You mentioned a tax credit, I'm not sure I can think of any relevant tax credit in this context, so I really can't tell what you're talking about.

As to the other person - if he's the one renting, *his* portion of the house, and *he* is receiving the income, then it has nothing to do with you.

Comment: I'm referring to writing off the mortgage interest as well as the real estate taxes.  Basically, I've got a mortgage for my half of home while they paid cash for their half of the home.

Comment: If you're not living in the house you cannot deduct anything. If you're using it to produce income (i.e.: you're renting it out), you can deduct it as rental expense, otherwise - its non-deductible personal expense.

Comment: If you bought half with a mortgage, why are you not collecting half the rent?

Comment: I wonder why the downvote...